# Error unreadable when attempting add new tag

Tags: bug, tags, user-interface, privileges, posting

I tried to submit a question, but I kept being told that I couldn't submit and that I should "check the error above."

There was no visible error. I had to find it in the source for the page. It turned out that I added the tag "controllerfactory". Since that was a *new* tag, I couldn't create the question because I don't yet have enough reputation to create new tags.

Comment: The error message appears on the right-hand side, see http://i.stack.imgur.com/pV4uD.png

Comment: @MartijnPieters: But's it's kinda hard to see, it blends into the page.

Comment: Excellent (but dupe) report with screenshot: [Make error notifications in posts more obvious/visible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167588)

Comment: Are these the same error message styles though? (I haven't seen either myself)

Comment: @BenBrocka: I'm going to assume so, as the message below the textbox is the same.

Comment: @gnat: I threw up an answer here with a chopped up version of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a *visible* error, it's just a little hard to see.  This is what I assume your screen looked like:

> [image: Where's the error?]

Turns out there actually is an error here.  Somewhere.  Good luck hunting for it. :-)

It took me a while of staring at this screen to find the error.  It's hidden on the right.  Blended in with the Careers 2.0 ad.

> [image: The Error!]

I think this error message should be made **way** more obvious.  As we can see, it's hard for people to find.

<sub>Answer adapted from my "duplicate" question: [Make error notifications in posts more obvious/visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167588/152620)</sub>

Comment: @gnat: I didn't realize you could wrap images in blockquotes.  That does make screenshots nicer looking in posts! :-)

Comment: note also tooltips :)

Comment: It may be that it popped up on the right.  Some text also flashed between the input box and the preview and that's where I ended up concentrating.  Maybe I was lazy when I just viewed the source. :)