# Getting "Please see the error above" but no error is visible for new questions in IE8

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, internet-explorer-8

I've never posted on Stack Overflow before, so this is my first attempt. I've drafted my question but when I try to submit it, it says:

> Your question couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.

This would be fine if it actually highlighted an error, but there's no reason I can see why my question isn't posting.  **Note there is no error in the sidebar as there is in other bug reports**.

Unlike in [Make error notifications in posts more obvious/visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167588/make-error-notifications-in-posts-more-obvious-visible) (which is about editing), I see no error at all while trying to post a new question in IE8.

In Chrome, I got an error about tags, so could post my question after all.

This is in IE8:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Take a screen shot and post a link to it so we can all see what you're seeing. Otherwise it's just conjecture. Alternatively edit the question you are trying to post in here **exactly as you are posting it on SO**.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't yet figured out how to post an image on SO so that may take me a while (I'm really, really new to programming!). I don't have the big red error message popping up like the person who posted "Make error notifications in posts more obvious/visible", but what does show up is a "How to format" dropdown menu. However, I've done everything that list asks me to do (e.g. indent code 4 spaces, for linebreaks add 2 spaces at end, etc.).

Comment: Sorry for the awful image quality

Comment: Check in the right side bar, do you see anything that indicates an error at all? What version of IE are you using?

Comment: I can see any error in the right side bar, no. I'm using IE version 8

Comment: [IE8 is no longer *officially* supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need), but I guess the error should still be visible. Any other browser you could try, so we know if it's related to a specific browser? Just login and you'll find the draft of your question in that browser too.

Comment: Arjan, Thank you so much! Turns out I was accidentally trying to create new tags but didn't have enough reputation.

Comment: For me (IE7) the message was almost invisible, because it overlaid the ads in the rightmost column. Took some time to realize it wasn't a part of the ad!

Comment: @Bo, give [Make error notifications in posts more obvious/visible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167588/make-error-notifications-in-posts-more-obvious-visible) a vote then ;-) But if it works in IE7 ([4%...](http://theie7countdown.com/)) then it should also work in IE8 I guess. So maybe no error is really sent back to the browser. The OP should try in another browser to validate that.

Comment: @BoPersson, any chance you can try to post a new question with IE7 and JUST a new tag [on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) (or any site on which you don't have 300 rep), to see if IE7 shows [the "Creating the new tag 'my-new-tag' requires at least 300 reputation" error](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cBR5r.png)? Just type `my-new-tag` followed by a space. Thanks!

Comment: @Arjan - Not right now, sorry. I use IE7 at work, because I have to, and don't have access to that until next week.

Comment: **Voting to reopen** as this is about IE8 not showing ANY message. Could become status-declined, obviously, but still a different use case.

Comment: @Arjan: The edit that removes IE8 is made by some ordinary SO user. According to [this data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer#Desktop_Market_share_by_year_and_version), IE8 is still used by at least half of IE users, so I don't think SO/SE should drop support for IE8 yet.

Comment: @nhahtdh, still then, [apparently the official statement is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208) *"We support current and previous versions of all browsers with some reasonable amount of market share."* But I agree that the team probably wants IE8 to see the errors too, that's why I edited all those late details into the question and voted to reopen.

Comment: it worked after i removed one of my three tags (ubuntu) here [autoKey gtk 0.95.10 Icon get red an autoKey freezing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64760245/autokey-gtk-0-95-10-icon-get-red-an-autokey-freezing)

Answer (score 6):

As I was using IE8, which is unsupported, I tried to post in google chrome. Turns out IE8 just didn't show an error message and I was accidentally trying to create two new tags without having enough reputation - so I changed those tags and my question posted. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this.. I tried in IE8, and received the expected error message. Do you mind providing any other details which might aid in debugging? e.g. the OS you're using or any javascript errors?

Comment: I don't even know what an OS is. I cannot stress how little I know about computers (and yes, I realise that it is ironic that I am on this site!). Were you trying it from your account, because like I said, the thing that was stopping me from posting was not being able to create tags because I had such a low reputation not having posted here before. I double it would be a common problem for people using the site. But if you can explain what an OS is or how I would know if there were javascript errors, I'd be happy to try and give you any more information that may be helpful.

Comment: @Emmett, in IE9, for some user(s?) [messages seem to be disappearing right after being shown](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168467/disappearing-error-message). Maybe this was the case in IE8 too?

Answer (score 5):

I never managed to reproduce this, but I *think* it was caused by a js timing issue, which we fixed yesterday. (One user who reported to have experienced the bug has confirmed that it works for them now.)

Comment: Looks like it also fixed ages old bug that caused the title in user profile page to disappear.. cheers!