# Can not post a question. It says see error above, but there is no error

Tags: support, posting

I am trying to post a question, but I get:

> Your question couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.

But there is no error above. There is a right panel about formatting, but I do not see anything wrong and am not sure what the error is. How can I see what the error it is so I can post the question?

Your popup error message does not stay open or never opens.

Comment: Ah, someone posted a helpful link but deleted that: see also [Getting “Please see the error above” but no error is visible for new questions in IE8](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167822/getting-please-see-the-error-above-but-no-error-is-visible-for-new-questions-i), and when using IE8: use another browser.