# Disappearing error message in IE9

Tags: bug, status-norepro, error-message, internet-explorer-9

When I try to ask a question in the regular site, I get an error message somewhere at the top of the page.  Unfortunately, the error box appears for a few milliseconds and is barely there long enough to notice it and not nearly long enough to read it.

How can I find out what the error message is so I can fix it and submit my question?

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that.  IE9 on Windows 7

Comment: Ah, then [Getting “Please see the error above” but no error is visible for new questions in IE8](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167822/getting-please-see-the-error-above-but-no-error-is-visible-for-new-questions-i) might apply to IE9 too.

Comment: Nobody here can reproduce it, but we're still working on it

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume this has been fixed. As a side note, we don't support this version of IE.

Comment: why no stack exchange support teh ie6?

Comment: what about ie 5?

Comment: Also: we don't support [Active Desktop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Desktop) (sorry!)