# "An error occurred submitting the question."

Tags: support, bug, answers

After filling in the title and question fields, then three tags, I clicked on the submit button. Over and over I get the above message in a dark red box right next to the submit button. I can't see any errors on my part that is generating that error message.

Error generated in FF 19.0.2 and Chrome 25.0.1364.155.

I've submitted other questions earlier, so this is not a repeatable bug.

Comment: Look to the right of the *question* box to see what the error is.

Comment: Related?: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167588/make-error-notifications-in-posts-more-obvious-visible

Comment: I see a color box with a How to Tag heading. That it? I had three tags and all were already in use.

Comment: Wesley: Possibly, except there, the error is being explained. In my case, it's not apparent that any error is being explained. It doesn't tell me what to change, and the tags are not the problem.

Comment: On March 20 I tried again and got the same error. I can post on other forums with no problems. Just not SO.

Comment: Was there link-like text inside parentheses or angle brackets? I’ve found that both `<foo@example.com>` and `(foo@example.com)` will prevent a question—or answer—from being submitted; see my post, _[“An error occurred submitting the answer.”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171916/155837)_

Comment: Same problem, and nothing about the error, it shows nothing.

Comment: Everything is okay, the title, the number of characters (not too long), the tags, "your question is ready to publish" -> An error occurred submitting the question.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted the question, but cut out around 15 lines of text, and it got through. Evidently it was beyond character limits, and that's what threw the generic error.

Character counting validation seems to be an easy addition and would have solved a bit of grief!

Thanks.

Comment: There is an error message specifically for posts that are too long, but your post doesn't seem anywhere near the 30,000-character limit.

Comment: Then my conclusion was wrong and I'm back to square one.

Comment: I have the same error, and my question is only 5 or 6 lines, maybe it's the opposite? Too short? They should fix the lack of message!