# “An error occurred submitting the answer.”

Tags: support, bug, answers, error-message, special-characters

Related: *["An error occurred submitting the question."](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/171003/155837)*

I’m trying to post an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8147805/95580) and keep getting the error message, “An error occurred submitting the answer.”

Thinking my original answer (see https://gist.github.com/jcsalomon/5162987) was perhaps a bit link-heavy, I deleted *all* links, but still got the same error:

[image: Error message]

ETA 2013-04-28: I finally found what was causing the answer to be rejected. Text of the form

```
mailto:<rfc822-addr-spec>
```

seems to trigger something—link detection, perhaps?—that causes the post to be rejected. As a temporary work-around, I’ve replaced all ASCII angle brackets (the less-than and greater-than signs ‘`<`’ and ‘`>`’) with Unicode angle quotes (‘`‹`’ and ‘`›`’).

ETA 2014-05-01: Seems the issue has been resolved behind the scenes. I was able to successfully edit my answer into the correct form.

Comment: Must be a local problem, the post looks fine.

Comment: I was able to post that into the [sandbox](hthttp://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171917/140890) just fine.

Comment: Try removing the `mailto: blah` things maybe? (`mail&#8203;to: blah`?) (@Martin: I'm not sure the same filtering rules apply on meta and SO.)

Comment: You *normally* get a more detailed error message (at least more detailed than just `an error occurred`). Is there any more detail *next* to the post editing window? (to the right).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I looked next to the editing frame; nothing.

Comment: I just posted your answer to that question and got hit with a captcha, but actually posting it worked just fine (don't worry, I deleted it immediately!)

Comment: Still getting the same error.

Comment: For me, replacing `"WScript...` with `"W"&"Script...` solved issue...

Comment: I was running into this problem and it ended up fixing it to copy the text elsewhere, delete/discard the draft, refresh the page, and then post it again.

Answer (score 8):

I tried editing the answer myself to insert the proper characters and received an identical error. I decided to dig a little further and discovered that the request to POST the edit is being met with an HTTP 500 response code:

[image]

So this is more than simply a case of the answer being rejected for failing to meet some criteria - rather, it is a case of the website itself actually throwing an error.

---

**Edit:** things get weirder. I was able to successfully post the answer here on Meta:

> [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/178263#178263)

Comment: I tried a suggested edit, didn't work either. Maybe this is some sort of broken spam heuristic that's only active on big sites.

Comment: Keep in mind that on Stack Overflow there is server side quality filter which is turned off here on Meta. Most likely the server side validation aka quality filter crashed with unexpected error which resulted in what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes your Network Administrators might block code submission.  Pressing F12 in browsers like Chrome helps you to identify whether the submission goes past your network.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was simply not connected to the Internet!

I was writing an answer and did not notice when the internet connection was lost. I tried posting it and got your error:

> An error occurred submitting the answer.

I reconnected and all was fine and merry.

*Edit*: I know that this is not the answer in the OP's ***specific*** case. However, it is still a reason, and if anyone gets that error and comes to this page, it is possible my answer can help them.

Comment: My question makes it clear this was not the trouble.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon I know. That is why I said "_In __my__ case_, ...". This was the first post when I searched this problem. Hence, I thought I should add another possible cause for this error, for future readers.