# Can't post on Stack Overflow; is it because of the code I'm posting?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

I'm trying to post a question on Stack Overflow and I'm getting "an error occurred submitting the question." I suspect there's something in my code snippet. All my code is in code blocks, but I do have some SQL commands that could be causing a problem. As a matter of fact, I'm pretty sure that they are causing a problem, because when I try to type what the commands are in *this* question, I'm not able to post this question either. So how do I get around this?

As requested, I've tried to post a screenshot. I no longer have the original post and the error message, but I've got a screenshot showing the three commands, one of which was causing the error. But when I try to post the screenshot (a PNG file from my desktop), it tells me it can't reach imgur.

Comment: What are you trying to put in? Make the SQL invalid and try to input it again because without seeing what you are trying to input we have no idea. That being said, I really dont think the SQL is the problem.

Comment: If you think SQL is interfering with the posting of a question, copy the SQL to Pastebin and attach the link to your question.

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of the commands?

Comment: Are you also getting "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code"?

Comment: Related: [“An error occurred submitting the answer.”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171916/an-error-occurred-submitting-the-answer). This was also reproduced yesterday with some SQL that included table altering code, but I was able to make the edits without issues. This does sound like a bug to me.

Answer (score 7):

I'm retagging this to [support](/questions/tagged/support) because over the last couple years we figured out the cause here - and it's not on our end.

Typically what happens is that there's a particularly zealous firewall or anti-virus that gets twitchy over certain SQL and blocks the post submission. The workaround is to either remove the "offending" code or post over HTTPS.

Comment: Just changing the HTTP to HTTPS in URL worked for me.

Comment: If this is true, it should be marked as accepted. A moderator can do that?

Comment: @DavidBalažic A moderator can't mark an answer as accepted, no. But, this whole thing is moot anyway now that we use HTTPS by default and HTTP is unsupported.

Comment: I receive the same error over `https`

Answer (score 5):

Actually, I just figured it out. It was the SQL (I was creating a table, executing a query string, dropping a table). I'm not sure which of these was the problem, but I took them out of the code snippet and just described that part of the code. If it's too confusing for folks, I'll use Pastebin as Telthien suggested. Thanks!

Comment: It would probably still be useful if you posted a screenshot of the commands, in-case future users encounter this problem

Comment: Add this to your main question and retag it as [meta-tag:bug]; this is a code help site. There should be no code users can't post.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me today. After removing the SQL code from [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35637735/822870), it worked. The SQL code was:

Ehh, can not submit it here either. Put it [on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/KyXpSXAU).

In both cases (new question and this edit*) it "spins" for like 10 seconds and then shows the error.

[image]

* I first added this to the question, but it was rejected

Answer (score 1):

In my case, only when posting a question to Stack Overflow from my work laptop, it was failing with some error. Only when I removed this part from my post, it was successful:

(Note: Even with this post here on Stack Exchange, I faced the same problem. I did try to find out what was causing the post to be blocked by making a number of edits. Finally, I found out that the part `new java` in the code below is causing the post to be blocked. But when I replaced this part with `new xxxx` it worked. See the snapshot below)

```
            httpsURLCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (isSslFlag) {
                String securedProtocol = "TLSv1.2";
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance(securedProtocol);
                sc.init(null, null, new xxxx.security.SecureRandom());
                httpsURLCon.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            }
            httpsURLCon.setDoOutput(true);
            httpsURLCon.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
            httpsURLCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", contentType);
            System.out.println("Request Method: " + requestMethod + " Content Type: " + contentType);
            String client_id = "client-id-value";
            String client_secret = "client-secret-value";
            String grant_type = "client_credentials";
            String scope = "scope-value";
```

But, I was able to post successfully from my mobile browser even with the above code part. Can someone explain why?

I even tried to contact Stack Overflow by submitting a form, from contact us, it didn't work from my work laptop, but it worked from my mobile browser.

I guess it is something at my end causing such issues but not 100% sure. This is because I was able to perform the same action from my mobile browser without any issues.

[image]

Comment: *[Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)* (the last section)

Comment: Do you mean I am not supposed to post this answer here? Can you please clarify?

Comment: No, the ***spelling***. Less subtle: section *"Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"*

Comment: Corrected the post.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I included CSS:

```
html, body {width: 400px;}
```

in a code snippet. Removing this allowed me to post the code.

Comment: CSS should come in its own section, you probably put it as part of the HTML.