# “An error occurred submitting the question.” with MSSQL query text

Tags: bug

I just attempted to post a sql query to SO. Upon attempting to post it, I got an extremely unhelpful error, "An error occurred submitting the question". I know it's something to do with the query, as I tried submitting without it, and of course that submitted fine, too bad for me (given that in the 8 seconds between submitting the post and deleting it, someone downvoted me for not including the query, durp. At least rep gets added back a couple minutes later if you delete your question, I also just learned...)

Of course I can't submit the query in this question here, either, with the same error, so as was requested in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176313/cant-post-to-so-is-it-because-of-the-code-im-posting), I'm attaching it externally (this is not a dup, due to the fact that the guy in that question didn't actually post his code on request, so it couldn't be reproduced).

edit: apparently, as was discovered, you can't submit it, but you can edit it in. This is indeed the same query I couldn't submit originally:

```
Declare @result VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @result = ''

SELECT @result += temp.temp
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ('Posted Date' + CAST(POSTED_DATE as char) + ',') as temp
  FROM [LACDC].[dbo].[PS_CDC_JRNL_LSR_VW]
  where JOURNAL_ID = @ID and JOURNAL_DATE = @Date
) AS temp
```

So, first question, is this a bug? I'm guessing it is, but correlarily, if there *are* characters or sequences of characters that I actually am not allowed to put in a question, could the specifics of that requirement at least be made more obvious? I do see a couple other posts on meta.SO with that same error, but one says the answer is don't submit questions more than 30,000 characters (my question was about 1,000) and was then marked as a dup of another one that says errors should be more obvious, as they're currently tucked away in a corner ("right of the textbox, blended in with the Careers 2.0 ad." - I don't see either of those things.)

(Also amusingly, in the time between when I tried unsuccessfully to post that to SO, and now, I figured out the issue with the query on my own, so thanks SO for being a good teddy bear!)

Comment: I was able to edit your question and include the query (the edit is in the edit queue though).

Comment: @Stijn Weird, I definitely reproduced not being able to add it here. Maybe editing goes through a different code path than creating a new question? I admittedly didn't try that.

Comment: @Stijn not really relevant, Meta got no quality filters.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd OP did mention he also tried to include the query in this meta question.

Comment: @Stijn oh, missed that. So maybe we're dealing with browser plugin breaking things - it won't be the first time.

Comment: @neminem what browser you use exactly? Can you try and disable all extensions/plugins/add-ons of the browser to see if it helps?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Conveniently, I checked (using the formatting sandbox), and I couldn't post the same post as an answer, either, with an equivalent error ("an error occurred submitting the answer"). I'm running FF26.0, and it certainly has a bunch of plugins, but I just tried posting it the same place on a very stock Chrome install (31.0.1650.57 m), and got the same error.

Comment: Off topic to your question here but that approach to string concatenation in SQL Server is [not guaranteed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138593/nvarchar-concatenation-index-nvarcharmax-inexplicable-behavior/15163136#15163136) and prone to breaking if  the execution plan changes. Better to use `XML PATH`

Comment: @MartinSmith Indeed offtopic, since the original question I was trying to post made it quite clear that I was working in an *extremely* legacy system (sql2000, we have no control over it), or none of this would have been necessary. (The original question being, "why does that query work in sql2008 but not in sql2000", and the answer was, "because sql2000 didn't even support the += operator".) The original query back in the beginning *did* use XML Path, which of course, is also not supported, we discovered the first time we deployed. :(

Comment: (As a different, off-topic and completely pedantic aside, [don't ever declare/define variable types like `char` without length in T-SQL](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). This has nothing to do with version, like the other problems you've encountered, but it will bite you later if you continue to use it. Another piece of advice is to not develop on a later version than the one you're deploying to.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand The first, where am I doing that? I'm not an expert at all, but I only see one declare, and it's declared as the max for sql2000, 8000 characters? To the second, yes, I would like that very much, I've been asking for a VM with sql2000 on it, but we don't have one. (We don't have any direct access to this particular client's system, we can only give them sessions and have them run them.)

Comment: @neminem `CAST(POSTED_DATE as char)`

Comment: @AaronBertrand Huh, that counts? I really would have assumed that if you CAST, it would give you a string the size of the item you just casted, since it would know what size that is by that point. It doesn't!? That is craziness, but if so, also good to know. (And yes, this is totally off topic.)

Comment: @neminem try `SELECT CAST('1234567890 1234567890 1234567890' AS CHAR);` - or [just read the link](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). In some cases it defaults to 1, in others 30; in both cases it can silently truncate, so you don't even know you've lost data.

Comment: I was able to post the code in the sandbox as an answer without editing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208923/197656

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Ok, that is crazy. Maybe you can, but I can't. I clicked on your link, copy-pasted the exact post you made into a new answer, clicked submit, got the same error. Just for kicks, I tried again not only on Chrome, but also in IE10 this time. Same generic "error occurred submitting the answer" all three times.

Comment: @neminem If I remember correctly, another user had a similar user, and it was caused by a proxy/firewall that rejected POST bodies it deemed potentially dangerous. Maybe try from a different network connection. That wouldn't explain why an edit works though.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Oh! I am behind a work firewall, it has done weird things with posts on other sites in the past. I hadn't thought of that. I'll try from a session remoting into my computer at home.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Yep, that's monumentally dumb, it was definitely the fault of the data getting munged on our end, and that does make sense now why I couldn't get a useful error message out of it. Thanks! (If you want meta rep, feel free to post that this was the answer, and I can accept it. I'd post the answer myself, but it was after all your answer. :p)

Comment: @neminem I'd rather get it closed as a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43466/197656.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire Well, it's not an exact dup, since it's not the same error, but sure.

Comment: @neminem I'd guess that when that post was made, questions weren't POSTed using AJAX as they are now. Instead, the entire page was posted. Now, the browser gets the same error, but only on the AJAX request, so the JS handles the error by showing the error message you got. I've flagged this as a dupe, so I'll let the 3k users handle the rest.

Comment: @JoshuaDwire That makes sense. I suppose it does make sense to dup them together then, so that people searching for this error find this post and get linked to the previous one.